# Vue: How do I call a function inside a Component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I am trying to execute a function from the Food.vue component from Page.vue.

How can I execute a function from an imported component?

I am using Vue 3 Composition API.

This is what I am trying to do:

## Food.vue Component

```
<script setup>
var food = "blueberry"

function changeFood () {
    
    food = "cherry";

}
</script>

<template>
    <div>{{food}}</div>
</template>
```

## Page.vue

```
<script setup>
import { onMounted } from "vue";
import food from "@/components/Food.vue";

onMounted(async() => {

    // I want to execute changeFood() from the imported component. How can I do this?

});
</script>


<template>
    <food></food>
</template>
```

I know this can be done with page props, but that's not what Im trying to do. I am trying to execute a function.

Comment: Just so that somebody has said it: In Vue, you try to avoid directly calling a method on a child like the plague.

Comment: In other words, this looks to be [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask "how do I fix this code problem" when the best solution is to use a different approach entirely.

Answer (score 2):

You have to expose the method to the parent using defineExpose;

### Food.vue

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

const food = ref("blueberry");

const changeFood = () => {
    food.value = "cherry";
};

defineExpose({ changeFood });
</script>

<template>
    <div>{{food}}</div>
</template>
```

### Page.vue

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import food from "@/components/Food.vue";

const myFood = ref(null);

onMounted(async() => {
    if (myFood.value) {
        myFood.value.changeFood();
    }
});
</script>


<template>
    <food ref="myFood" />
</template>
```

[Demo](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Hmm did not work....

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'changeFood')

Comment: Did not work still....

Comment: My mistake - should work flawlessly now @hehe

Comment: `if (myFood.value)` check is unnecessary

Comment: That is true, but better safe than sorry no?

Comment: Still not working

Comment: It's working in the demo. Do you have any console errors?

Comment: If I remove `if (myFood.value)`, then I still get the error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'changeFood')

Comment: Did you forget to add `ref="myFood"` to the template?

Comment: No my template has ref="myFood"

Comment: Please make sure that you copied everything appropriately. The code should be working as seen in the demo. Also, reload the browser just in case